# Java - Casting user's input, which contains both integers and doubles into an array

Tags: java

I'm brand new to Java. At the moment I have been given the problem of casting a 3-by-4 array using a user's input of specific numbers as follows:
2.6   5.1   6   8 
5.4   4.4   7   1 
9.5   7.9   2   3

Right now, I have got it to work solely for integers, and structured it as such, as I cannot wrap my head around multiple inputs from the user.

What I have if I just use integers (Such as 5 instead of 5.1, and 2, instead of 2.6 etc.) is as follows:

```
    int row, col;
    int i, j;
    int data[][] = new int[4][3];


    col = 3;
    row = 4;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // enter array elements.
    System.out.println("Enter the provided Array Elements : ");
    //Works with integers as input only at the moment.

    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

What I would like is to convert all of the user's input to read as a double data type, and cast the double data types into the array.

Any insight on how to cast them would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use scan.nextDouble() to read floating point numbers. declare everything as double from array to all variables

Comment: Use only `double`s, without `int`s.

Comment: 1. change the data types from int to double . 2. datat[i][j] = scan.nextDouble(); . this should be easiest for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast arrays in java like you'd probbaly expect. For example, you aren't allowed to do the following operations:

```java
int[] i = new int[0];
double[] d = (double[]) i;
```

This means, you need to declare your array simply as double[] and replace `scan.nextInt()` with `scan.nextDouble()` and that's it.

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly now. I just completely overlooked declaring the users input, and this was a much needed reminder for future reference.